# Android clang and llvm error unable to execute command: Segmentation fault

Tags: android, llvm-clang

As I'm building android oreo for msm8996. I'm getting this error without my knowledge. Please give me a suggestive solution to kickoff my build. 
Error occured like this screenshot
[image]

Comment: add error message as text, not as image

Comment: In addition to the comment from @barbsan- it would help if you went into more detail on the steps you went through to build AOSP. Have you run `source build/envsetup.sh` and run `lunch` to specify the build target, for instance?